# Why can't this integrator amplifier give a square wave output?

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal, simulation

I am trying to integrate a triangle signal using an opamp as integrator. I was expecting a square wave, but the output signal looks like this:

[image]

The signal isn't totally squared (I am working based on the ideal model) and the amplitude is very low.

[Simulation circuit](http://%3Ciframe%20width=%22800%22%20height=%22600%22%20src=%22https://www.multisim.com/content/huDBVknrTaNgT72jBBA8kP/integrator-opamp/open%22%3E%3C/iframe%3E)
[[image]

Multisim Live: Integrator opamp](https://www.multisim.com/content/huDBVknrTaNgT72jBBA8kP/integrator-opamp/)

I was expecting something in the range of
\$V_o\$ \$=\frac{T}{RC}\$ \$V_i\$=\$\frac{0.001s}{1k\Omega(100nF)}\$ \$(1V)=10\,V\$

Why isn't the signal totally squared and why is the amplitude so low?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **derivative** of a triangle is a square wave. The integral is something else that looks (sort-of) sinusoidal. So it's good it doesn't look square.

Anyway, your integrator is saturating. That accounts for the output being at the supply rail. You can prevent that by paralleling the capacitor with a resistor (try 100K, but I'm not sure what op-amp model they are using).

Comment: Ok, thanks for showing the conceptual error.